# “How to fix datatype in pandas-dataframe which gives an Value error ?”ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-- '

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working with a Youtube dataset. But when I try to convert the datatype of a column I get a Value Error. How do I fix it?
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-- '

Answer (score 0):

The ValueError says what the problem is : You have a string and you are using it as a float.

Please search for ways to do this, here is some material :
[How do I parse a string to a float or int in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/how-do-i-parse-a-string-to-a-float-or-int-in-python)